# Property of Holomorphic function on unit disc( How many functions exist in these exist )

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying assignment questions in complex analysis and I am struck on this question.

[image]

I am adding image for this particular question as it will take really long time to type this.

Attempt: clearly set S has f(z) =z but I don't know whether any other such f(z) exists.

Also for set T, I am unable to find any element and also a reason why no such element couldn't exist.

Comment: Hint: Use the [identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem).

Comment: Hint: Use the above hint.

Comment: @ShiveringSoldier So , using identity theorem S is singelton but T is $\phi$ . Am i right ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.